# Add list of dictionaries to dataframe as column headers and values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a bit new to pandas and I have a project whereby I have a dataframe of bitly links and their respective metrics. I have also collected country data for each bitly links and when the latter is parsed, it returns a list of dictionaries containing the County Codes and its respective number of clicks.

What I would like to do is to add the Country Codes to the existing bitly links dataframe as columns and then save the number of clicks for each countries into its specific bitly link row.
Would  be great if anyone can help me in this.

Pandas Dataframe of bitly_links:

```
index | link        | long_url            | created_at          | link_clicks |
------|-------------|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|
0     | bit.ly/aaaa | https://example.com | 2020-04-01 10:54:33 | 150         |
1     | bit.ly/bbbb | https://example.com | 2020-04-01 10:54:33 | 20          |
2     | bit.ly/cccc | https://example.com | 2020-04-01 10:54:33 | 15          |
3     | bit.ly/dddd | https://example.com | 2020-04-01 10:54:33 | 13          |
```

Python countries list for one specific bitly (e.g. bit.ly/aaaa) link:

```py
countries_data = [
                   {'country': 'US', 'clicks': 150}, {'country': 'UK', 'clicks': 20}, 
                   {'country': 'AU', 'clicks': 45}, {'country': 'ZS', 'clicks': 31}
                 ]

index | country | clicks |
------|---------|--------|
0     | US      | 150    |
1     | UK      | 20     |
2     | AU      | 45     |
3     | ZS      | 31     |
```

New dataframe that i want to make:

```
index | link        | long_url            | created_at          | link_clicks | US | UK | AU | ZS |
------|-------------|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|----|----|----|----|
0     | bit.ly/aaaa | https://example.com | 2020-04-01 10:54:33 | 110         | 20 | 30 | 10 | 50 |
1     | bit.ly/bbbb | https://example.com | 2020-04-01 10:54:33 | 89          | 25 | 41 | 11 | 12 |
2     | bit.ly/cccc | https://example.com | 2020-04-01 10:54:33 | 81          | 10 | 27 | 31 | 14 |
3     | bit.ly/dddd | https://example.com | 2020-04-01 10:54:33 | 126         | 11 | 74 | 31 | 10 |
```

Comment: Not sure why the values changed, can you explain the logic why `150` became `110`?

Comment: Because I didn't care enough to copy paste the data. I just keyed in any numbers available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have to do is tidy the data for country information for each click:

```
# I take the example with two lists for link-level data related to countries, but
#  it extends to more :
import pandas as pd
countries_data1 = [
                   {'country': 'US', 'clicks': 150}, {'country': 'UK', 'clicks': 20},
                   {'country': 'AU', 'clicks': 45}, {'country': 'ZS', 'clicks': 31}
                 ]
countries_data2 = [
                   {'country': 'US', 'clicks': 150}, {'country': 'UK', 'clicks': 20},
                   {'country': 'AU', 'clicks': 45}, {'country': 'ZS', 'clicks': 31}
                 ]
# transform to dataframe, add variable link, and concat
countries_data1 = pd.DataFrame(countries_data1).assign(link="bit.ly/aaaa")
countries_data2 = pd.DataFrame(countries_data2).assign(link="bit.ly/bbbb")
df = pd.concat([countries_data1, countries_data2]) # you will concat the list of all 
# your dataframes with link information regarding countries, here I only have 2 in
#  this example

# then go in wide format with pivot_table
df = df.pivot_table(index="link", values="clicks", columns="country")
```

You get this table :

```
country      AU  UK   US  ZS
link                        
bit.ly/aaaa  45  20  150  31
bit.ly/bbbb  45  20  150  31
```

```
# assume your first table (simplified) is : 
table = pd.DataFrame({"link": ["bit.ly/aaaa", "bit.ly/bbbb"],
                      "link_clicks": [150,20]})
# set the index for link
table = table.set_index("link")

# then do an outer join on link 
merge_df = pd.concat([table, df], join="outer", axis=1)
merge_df.head()
```

You get the result:

```
             link_clicks  AU  UK   US  ZS
link                                     
bit.ly/aaaa          150  45  20  150  31
bit.ly/bbbb           20  45  20  150  31
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. That's an awesome way to do it. I did not know about the pivot_table methods in Pandas. Will have a thorough look at it. Thanks again ^^

Comment: @Aditya Bholah Your welcome, if it is ok for you, could you mark it as the accepted answer ? Thanks